# Finding minimum and maximum of a function inside a triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an assignment I will hand in for grading.

*First part*

I want to see if I have understood the consept correctly.

Determine max and min of $f(x,y)=xy $ on the triangle T with the corners $(0, 0), (0, 1)\:and\:(1, 0)$

I derived and got a critical point at $(0,0)$ which I evaluated to $0$.

Secondly I inspected the boundary lines of which only the hypotenuse was interesting x+y=1 where I only found one critical point and that was larger than 0.

Is it correct minimum value was 0?

*Second part*

Are there any analytical online tools where I can write functions and boundaries and get the max and min values?

Comment: For the first part, you should also check the vertices of the triangle, for the same reason you check the boundaries of the domain.

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to find this question abandoned, so I thought I'd finish it.

It is clear that **Farmor** has already noted that setting $ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y \ $ and $ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x \ $ equal to zero locates the critical point at $ \ (0,0) \ , $ at which $ \ f(0,0) = 0 \ . $  The function is also zero at the boundaries of the triangle and at all three vertices (thus responding to **Daryl**'s remark, although OP may well have already done that if that is what was meant by having inspected the boundaries).  So the minimum value of the function in the region *is* zero, but that is not localized to a "critical point".

As for the boundary on $ \ x + y = 1 \ $  ,  the single-variable approach is to write $ \ f(x,y) = xy \ $ as $ \ f(x) = x \cdot (1-x) = x - x^2 \ , $ which has its maximum at $ \ f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4} \ $ (so identified since $ \ f'(\frac{1}{2}) = -2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} < 0 \ $ ) ; this can be found even without calculus by noting the properties of the "downward-facing" parabola $ \ y  = x - x^2 \ . $

Alternatively, we can use Lagrange multipliers with the function $ \ f(x,y) = xy \ $ under the constraint $ \ g(x,y) =  x + y - 1 \ , $ producing the equations

$$\begin{array}{cc}f_x \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ g_x\\f_y \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ g_y\end{array} \ \Rightarrow \ \begin{array}{cc}x \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 1\\y \ = \ \lambda \ \cdot \ 1\end{array} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \lambda \ = \ x \ = \ y \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ . $$

So we find what proves to be a local and absolute maximum, $ \ f(\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4} . $  The standard discriminant $ \ f_{xx} \cdot f_{yy} - ( f_{xy} )^2 = 0 \cdot 0 - 1^2 \ $ is of no help, however, in characterizing critical points for this function.